# PHP - upload PNG image transparent

Tags: php, upload, png, transparency, transparent

I would like to upload png images transparent, I tried many things via google but still didnt work, still background is black. Here is my code, it is written in symfony 2.7. It is uploading and creating two images, one is small, the second is big.

[Image before sending](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a80Zv.png)

[Image after sending](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Th6s.jpg)

So here you can see difference between images before upload and after upload.

```
if ($upload_type == 'image/png' || $upload_type == 'image/jpg' || $upload_type == 'image/jpeg' || $upload_type == 'image/gif') {
                $filename = stripslashes($upload_name);
                $extension = $this->getExtension($filename);
                $extension = strtolower($extension);

                if ($extension == "jpg" || $extension == "jpeg") {
                    $upload_temp = $_FILES['form-chat-send-image']['tmp_name'];
                    $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($upload_temp);
                } else if ($extension == "png") {
                    $upload_temp = $_FILES['form-chat-send-image']['tmp_name'];
                    $src = imagecreatefrompng($upload_temp);
                } else {
                    $src = imagecreatefromgif($upload_temp);
                }

                list($width, $height) = getimagesize($upload_temp);
                $newWidth1 = $width;
                $newHeight1 = $height;
                if($width>1200 || $height>1200) {
                    if ($height < $width) {
                        $newWidth1 = 1200;
                        $newHeight1 = ($height / $width) * $newWidth1;
                    } else {
                        $newHeight1 = 1200;
                        $newWidth1 = ($width / $height) * $newHeight1;
                    }
                }
                $tmp1 = imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth1, $newHeight1);
                $newWidth2 = $width;
                $newHeight2 = $height;
                if($width>220 || $height>220) {
                    if ($height < $width) {
                        $newWidth2 = 220;
                        $newHeight2 = ($height / $width) * $newWidth2;
                    } else {
                        $newHeight2 = 220;
                        $newWidth2 = ($width / $height) * $newHeight2;
                    }
                }
                $tmp2 = imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth2, $newHeight2);
                imagecolortransparent($tmp2, imagecolorallocate($tmp2, 0, 0, 0));
                imagealphablending( $tmp2, false );
                imagesavealpha( $tmp2, true );

                imagecopyresampled($tmp1, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newWidth1, $newHeight1,
                    $width, $height);

                imagecopyresampled($tmp2, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newWidth2, $newHeight2,
                    $width, $height);

                $dateName = new \DateTime();
                $newName = $conversation->getId().'-'.$dateName->format('m_d_Y_H_i_s');

                $filename1 = $uploadTo . $newName . "." . $extension;
                $filename2 = $uploadTo . "small/" . $newName . "." . $extension;

                imagejpeg($tmp1, $filename1, 100);
                imagejpeg($tmp2, $filename2, 100);

                imagedestroy($src);
                imagedestroy($tmp1);
                imagedestroy($tmp2);
                $uploadDB = $newName . "." . $extension;

                $msgImg = new Message();
                $msgImg->setText($uploadDB);
                $msgImg->setConversation($conversation);
                $msgImg->setForm('img');
                if($type==2){
                    $msgImg->setType(0);
                }
                else if($type==1){
                    $msgImg->setType(1);
                }
                $em->persist($msgImg);
                $em->flush();

                $_FILES = array();
                return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('conversation',array('id'=>$conversation->getId())));
            }
```

Comment: (Did you try saving&viewing the PNG locally? Results?)

Comment: locally ? if you mean localhost then it is the same as on server

Comment: *save/use locally* as in *without the upload* you seem to mistrust.

Comment: locally it has no black background, it is transparent, black is only when uploading

Comment: Please post a copy of your two images.

Comment: ok i edited question with images before/after

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            imagejpeg($tmp1, $filename1, 100);
            imagejpeg($tmp2, $filename2, 100);
```

JPEG does not support transparency. You need `imagepng` and use PNG format instead.

That being said, you seem to have code that loads in the image (using `imagecreatefrom*` as appropriate), why not do the same for saving (`image*`)?

Comment: thanks you a lot, I didnt realized that I am saving all images into jpeg format. :)